# Placing points randomly on a 2D board

Tags: android, arrays, random, 2d

How can I generate random points (tokens, stones...) on a 2D based game?

Tokens are a 2D array of points : 
`Token[][] gameBoard;`

Players are simply paint object. It contains colors of the token that will : `Paint bluePaint, redPaint;`

On initialization, I can manually place tokens arbitrarly on the board like below (from the onCreate method of the MainActivity):

```
bluePlayer = new Token(1,bluePaint, bgrBluePaint);
redPlayer = new Token(2, redPaint, bgrRedPaint);
gameBoard = new Token[100][100];

gameBoard[47][47]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[46][47]= bluePlayer;
gameBoard[44][48] = redPlayer; 
gameBoard[44][49]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[45][47]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[45][48]= bluePlayer;
gameBoard[45][49]= bluePlayer;
gameBoard[45][50]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[46][50]= bluePlayer;
gameBoard[46][49]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[46][48]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[47][50]= bluePlayer;
gameBoard[47][48]= bluePlayer;
gameBoard[47][49]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[48][50]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[48][49]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[48][48]= redPlayer;
gameBoard[49][50]= bluePlayer;
gameBoard[48][51]= redPlayer;
```

So my question is, how to randomly place redPlayer and bluePlayer within a given range of coordinates? I mean I would like them to be randomly placed at, say, in the cell surrounding the center of the board

```
class Token {

    private int _player;
    private Paint _paint, _bgrPaint;

    Token(int player, Paint paint, Paint bgrPaint) {
        _player = player;
        _paint = paint;
        _bgrPaint = bgrPaint;
    }

    Paint getPaint() {
        return _paint;
    }

    Paint get_bgrPaint() {
        return _bgrPaint;
    }

    int setPlayer(int _player, int _paint) {

        this._player = _paint;

        return _player;
    }

    int getPlayer() {
        return _player;
    }
}
```

Above is the Token class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Random` class:

```
import java.util.Random;

// ...

void generateTokens(int count) {
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean isRed = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int x = random.nextInt(100);
        int y = random.nextInt(100);

        gameBoard[x][y] = isRed ? redPlayer : bluePlayer;
        isRed = !isRed;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to restrict the placement of tokens to around the center of the board, the most straightforward way is to just restrict which squares the above function assigns to. The problem with that approach is as the size of the center gets smaller, the chance that you will write to a tile that has already been written to gets more likely.

Instead, you can pre-generate a list of all the tiles that will contain tokens. Afterwards, randomize the list, and then iterate through it, assigning each tile to either red or blue:

```
class Point { 
    public int X; 
    public int Y; 

    public Point(int x, int y) { 
        this.X = x; 
        this.Y = y;
    } 
}

// ...

void generateTokens(int centerRadius) {
    Random random = new Random();
    ArrayList<Point> positions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int x = 49 - centerRadius; x <= 50 + centerRadius; x++) {
        for (int y = 49 - centerRadius; y <= 50 + centerRadius; y++) {
            postions.add(new Point(x, y));
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(positions);

    boolean isRed = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < positions.GetLength(); i++) {
      Point p = positions.get(i);
        gameBoard[p.X][p.Y] = isRed ? redPlayer : bluePlayer;
        isRed = !isRed;
    }
}
```

(I'm not at a place where I can test this code, so it might need some tweaking to get it to work.)